# Tapir custom http code in successful response

Tags: scala, http, tapir

I'm using [Tapir library](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/) for endpoint definition but I need to provide custom http code in a successful response (not to map error to error code). I've found [something](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/v0.11.9/endpoint/statuscodes.html) in the documentation but it's not really useful to me. Could somebody give me simple code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always provide a given status code in case of a successful response, adding the following output should work:

```scala
import sttp.model.StatusCode

myEndpoint.out(statusCode(StatusCodes.Created))
```

Alternatively, you can add a dynamic status code output:

```scala
import sttp.model.StatusCode

myEndpoint.out(statusCode)
```

Then you'll need to provide the `StatusCode` value as part of the business logic.

Comment: Does that dynamic status code output option allow you to *only* return a status code - no body? Is there a way to have a response be e.g. 200 OK + a JSON body, or 204 No Content and no body?

Comment: @pdxleif if you want to use different outputs depending on the status code, `oneOf` is what you're looking for: https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/oneof.html (the example there even uses `204`)